# HTML code being placed as text instead of being rendered -- Updated

Tags: javascript, html

I had recently asked a question, and I had not put enough details in. This is my new question with more code and details.

I am trying to set the value of `document.getElementById("affiliates-container-row").innerHTML` to an a different HTML code, in a variable called `output`.

The result I am getting when setting `document.getElementById("affiliates-container-row").innerHTML = output` is un-rendered, text. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKk0Y.png)

I have a `compileAffiliates` script which I run through the index.js, which returns the value of output. Here is the code, it takes all of the values of a config.json file and puts them into the divs individually, which can be seen in the compileAffiliates.js file. (below)

```
let config = require("./config");

function start() {
    let output = ``;

    Object.keys(config.websiteAffiliates).forEach(key => {
        output += `<div class=col-md-3>
   <div class="site-affiliate-container">
      <img src="images/${config.websiteAffiliates[key].imgSrc}">
      <div class="row row-style">
         <div class="col col-style"><span>${config.websiteAffiliates[key].refBonus}</span></div>
         <div class="col col-style"><span>Code ${config.websiteAffiliates[key].refCode}</span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row row-style"><button class="button button-type"><a href="${config.websiteAffiliates[key].imgLink}">Use Code</a></button></div>
   </div>
</div>`
    });
    return output;
}

module.exports = {start};
```

In Index.js, I required and ran `compileAffiliates.start()` and set that value to `output` which is passed on to the hbs file by the variable of output. I'm using express so it looks like:

```
let compileAffiliates = require("./compileAffiliates");
let output = compileAffiliates.start();

app.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
    res.render("main", {config: config, output: output});
});
```

My `main.hbs` file has this script:

```
<script>
        let output = '{{output}}';

        document.getElementById("affiliate-container-row").innerHTML = output;
    </script>
```

The code above is where the issue is seen. The main page should now display the HTML code from output, but instead, it shows the code from output as un-rendered text.

I've been trying to solve this issue but through research, I've done on both StackOverflow and Google generally, I can't find a solution that fits the issue I'm having.

The issue is that it is displayed inside of the div `affiliate-container-row` as text, as opposed to the HTML code I want it to display. It will display the String version of `output`, instead of it being rendered as the HTML code itself.

I have written a JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/h39t42qu/1/) which shows the code, with the 2 different JS files, combined. In this form, it works since there is no transfer needed from JS file to JS file. In my actual project, where it is required for me to go between 2 different JS files (compileAffiliates.js -> index.js). The final result of my projects code ends up looking like this screenshot (https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKk0Y.png). I'm completely lost as to how to fix this issue, as the JSFiddle shows what I want to be shown and the result I get on my end is completely different. I posted a public GitHub repo (https://github.com/dpressd/stackoverflow-issue) with ALL my code.

Any help at all towards fixing the issue is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: First of all your Dom node is not valid. The first div needs double quotes around classname, and dont put a link inside the div :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `{{{expression}}}` instead of `{{expression}}`.

Inside `main.hbs`,

`let output = {{{output}}};`

You can find a better explanation in the handlebars documentation.

[HTML-escaping](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#literal-segments)

Answer (score 1):

Better go with the DOM Manipulation approach, in this basically you write JS code to generate HTML and keep appending that as a child node to the target element.

You can refer to this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents) to learn more about DOM Manipulation.

Comment: Let me know if you are facing any issue with that